# Diseño de una buscador flotante - css - ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Hola estoy tratando de poner mi buscador en la parte de arriba, haste el momento :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en la imagen inferior mi buscador esta muy abajo lo que intento hacer es poerlo en la parte de arriba abajo de tollbar

**Esto es mi css**

```
.buscador {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
        width: 90%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 100;
        opacity: .9;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu problema esta en esto: 
**bottom: 20px;** ya que hace que la clase .buscador se vaya a la parte inferior de la pagina

```css
.buscador {
   position: fixed;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
             margin-top: 10%;
   width: 90%;
   border-radius: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   z-index: 100;
   opacity: .9;
  }
```

```html
<div class="buscador" style="background-color: black; height: 90px;>

 </div>
```

luego solo juegas con el **margin-top:10%;** para colocar tu buscador en la parte que gustes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la pornta respuesta